# XML new lined inner text

Tags: c#, .net, xml, newline, indentation

I'm working with XMLs and I have this problem: I want to add an inner text on a single line separated by opening and closing element tags. Something like this:

```
<root>
 <child name="name">
  Hi! I'm inner text!
 </child>
</root>
```

but if I add the inner text with:

```
child.InnerText = "Hi! I'm inner text!";
```

I have all on the same line:

```
<root>
 <child name="name">Hi! I'm inner text!</child>
</root>
```

I tried to add:

```
xDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

before Save function with no result. Tried with:

```
child.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateWhitespace("\n"));
```

after or before the InnerText instruction. Nothing. Some help?

EDIT: This is how I save the XML:

```
xDoc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Have you tried `child.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateWhitespace("\nHi! I'm inner text!\n"));` ?

Comment: If whitespaces are meaningfull, you should consider using a `<![CDATA[ text with whitespaces]]>` section. See [XmlDocument.CreateCDataSection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection)

Comment: can you show the code for xDoc.Save and XDoc.PreserveWhitesapce you used

Comment: @machineghost: it doesn't work

Comment: @Steve B: It works but I want only the text without [[CDATA] construct

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different options. You can set InnerText of the XmlElement or append a text node.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

XmlNode root = xDoc.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("root"));
XmlNode child = root.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("child"));

((XmlElement)child).InnerText = "\nHi! I'm Inner Text!\n";
child.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateTextNode("\nHi! I'm also Inner Text\n"));
xDoc.Save(@"c:\temp\temp.xml");
Debug.Write(xDoc.InnerXml.ToString());
```

Keep in mind that, depending on how you look at the generated XML, you may not see the newlines produced in the document. IE, for example, will happily ignore them when showing you the pretty version of the document.

Comment: it doesn't work, I have "Hi! I'm Inner Text! Hi! I'm also Inner Text" all in the same line (and obviously in the tag one)

Comment: How are you looking at the XML? Crack it open in a text editor.

Comment: Also, the PreserveWhitespace = true part was outside the code quote block, so you may have missed it. I've edited to fix my formatting mistake.